# How do I get Vim colorschemes to work in gnome-terminal?

Tags: vim

I have added this to .vimrc

```
set t_Co=256
```

That did not seem to have an effect.

I am using the "wombat.vim" color scheme from the vim.org website. This works fine in vim-gnome, the gui version. I have tried other color schemes and some work and some do not. If gnome-terminal will not work with the color schemes is there a terminal that will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wombat colorscheme doesn't define colors for anything other than the gui.  You can use the [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) plugin to allow using gui-only colorschemes in terminal vim.

Of course, once you do that there's still the issue of gnome-terminal not specifying the right `$TERM` for itself, so you have to either

- Put code in your vimrc to try and detect when you're using gnome-terminal and only then manually set t_Co.  CSApprox's documentation has an example.
- Put code in your shell init file to try and detect when you're using gnome-terminal and only then manually set `$TERM` to a proper value
- Convince Gnome upstream to fix the [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115750) that's been sitting in their tracker for years to either allow users to set a proper `$TERM` (without having to edit the source and recompile) or to set it properly in the first place

  - It looks like they may finally be getting around to the first option and making it configurable via gconf/gsettings

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable 256-color support.

To do that, you need to put the following line in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.profile` file:

```
export TERM="gnome-256color"
```

Comment: gnome-256color would be the proper TERM setting, and it should really only be set if you're using gnome-terminal since other terminals actually know how to set a proper TERM on their own.